# using each_slice and sort Ruby

Tags: ruby

I need to reorganize an array into slices of 2 elements and then sort each slice alphabetically using each_slice

I've managed to get the each_slice correctly but I can seem to then sort each sub array.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
array.each_slice(2).to_a { |el| el = el.sort}
```

Comment: Do you know how stack over flow works? If you rise a question, then you have to choose the best answer by accepting one of them. But I see many questions you raised and you did not accept any of the answers so far and you did not even reply to anyone either.

Comment: Hi Rajagopalan. I did not know that, thanks for the alert

Comment: Consider `[2,1,3,4].each_slice(2).map { |el| el.sort } #=> [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, which can also be written `array.each_slice(2).map(&:sort)`.

Comment: @Peter muller sure, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to create a new array with the output that you want.
For instance:

```rb
# $ array = ["b", "a", "d", "c", "k", "l", "p"]
arr = []
array.each_slice(2) { |el| arr << el.sort}
# $ arr
# => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["k", "l"], ["p"]]
```

EDIT:

Pointed in the comments (by @mu is too short), you can also do:

```
arr = array.each_slice(2).map(&:sort)
```

Comment: Or more idiomatically: `arr = array.each_slice(2).map(&:sort)`.